# Remove text after link

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

So I have an `@mentions` function on my site that users input themselves but can do something line:

> @foo Hello This is some mention text included.

I would like to remove just the text (Everything after @foo) The content comes through the `streamitem_content`:

```
$json['streamitem_content_usertagged'] =
preg_replace('/(^|\s)@(\w+)/', '\1@<a href="profile.php?username=$1">$1</a>',
$json['streamitem_content']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try

```
$json['streamitem_content'] = '@foo Hello This is some mention text included.';
$json['streamitem_content_usertagged'] =
preg_replace('/@(\w+)/', '@<a href="profile.php?username=$1">$1</a>',
$json['streamitem_content']);
echo $json['streamitem_content_usertagged'];
```

Output:

```
@<a href="profile.php?username=foo">foo</a> Hello This is some mention text included.
```

`Preg_replace` will only replace what it finds so you don't need to find content you aren't interested. If you did want to capture multiple parts of a string though capture groups increase by one after each group `()`. So this

```
preg_replace('/(^|\s)@(\w+)/', '$1@<a href="profile.php?username=$2">$2</a>',
$json['streamitem_content']);  
echo $json['streamitem_content_usertagged'];
```

would actually be

```
preg_replace('/(^|\s)@(\w+)/', '$1@<a href="profile.php?username=$2">$2</a>',
$json['streamitem_content']);
```

**Update:**

```
$json['streamitem_content'] = '@foo Hello This is some mention text included.';
$json['streamitem_content_usertagged'] =
preg_replace('/@(\w+).*$/', '@<a href="profile.php?username=$1">$1</a>',
$json['streamitem_content']);
echo $json['streamitem_content_usertagged'];
```

Output:

```
@<a href="profile.php?username=foo">foo</a>
```

If the content you want to replace after `@foo` can extended to multiple lines use the `s` [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/tX1rO0/1

So pretty much the regex says find an `@` then capture all continuous `a-zA-Z0-9_` characters. After a those continuos characters we don't care go to the end of the string.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I was clear. I just don't want the text after the '@foo

Comment: So just `@text` until a whitespace then remove all other content?

Comment: Updated the question so there is no confusion to others.

Comment: I'm sorry Chris but your code doesn't seem to solve the issue and text is still included after @foo

Comment: This is what I receive with the updated code in firebug


`{"streamitem_id":"1086","streamitem_content":"<a href=\"profile.php?username=Luce\">Luce<\/a> dddd",`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95743/discussion-between-chris85-and-the-river-scene-music).

Comment: `explode()` should do that, then take the first part of the array `[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
preg_replace('/^\s*@(\w+)/', '<a href="profile.php?username=$1">@$1</a>',
             $json['streamitem_content']);
```

This removes the leading white space, and includes the @ in the hyperlink's text (not the link argument).

If you need to keep the leading white space in tact:

```
preg_replace('/^(\s*)@(\w+)/', '$1<a href="profile.php?username=$2">@$2</a>',
             $json['streamitem_content']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `explode();` and `str_replace();` . They might have a speed advantage over `preg`.

Assuming the line is available as a variable (e.g. `$mention`):

```
  $mention = $json['streamitem_content'];

  $mention_parts = explode(" ", $mention);
  $the_part_you_want = str_replace('@','', $mention_parts[0]);
   // or you could use $the_part_you_want = ltrim($mention_parts[0], '@');

  $json['streamitem_content_usertagged'] = '@<a href="profile.php?username=' . $the_part_you_want . '">' . $mention_parts[0] . '</a>';
```

or use `trim($mention_parts[0]);`  to remove any whitespace if it is unwanted.

You could use fewer variables and reuse `$mention` as array but this seemed a clearer way to illustrate the principle.